# Form validation angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have couple of fields in my form & I want to enable submit button if anyone of them is filled, how I can do this? If I put required to both or anyone of them then it won't work as I want.

```
<input type="text" name="phone">
<span ng-show="form.addContactForm.phone.$touched && form.addContactForm.phone.$error.required">Phone number or email is required</span>
<input type="text" name="email">
<span ng-show="form.addContactForm.email.$touched && form.addContactForm.email.$error.required">Phone number or email is required</span>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.addContactForm.$invalid || form.addContactForm.$submitted">Submit</button>
```

If phone or email is entered then other message should hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add the conditions in

```
<input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="ctrl.phone">
<span ng-show="(form.addContactForm.phone.$touched || form.addContactForm.email.$touched) && !ctrl.phone && !ctrl.email">Phone number or email is required</span>

<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="ctrl.email">
<span ng-show="(form.addContactForm.phone.$touched || form.addContactForm.email.$touched) && !ctrl.phone && !ctrl.email">Phone number or email is required</span>

<button type="submit" ng-disabled="(!ctrl.phone && !ctrl.email) || form.addContactForm.$invalid || form.addContactForm.$submitted">Submit</button>
```

Edit: Add error message and condition

Comment: Ok thanks also I need to show the message as well, edited my question please check

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution, if this form is all you have: Use `ng-required` and make the condition in each field *dependent* on the other field. I even added a `ng-disabled` so that, if a field is filled-in, the other becomes disabled. I did not include the error messages for clarity - use the `<span>`s you already have.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as c">
  <form name="contactForm">
    <input ng-model="c.phone" type="text" name="phone"
            ng-required="!c.email" ng-disabled="c.email" />
    <input ng-model="c.email" type="text" name="email"
            ng-required="!c.phone" ng-disabled="c.phone" />
    <button ng-disabled="contactForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Relevant fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0L7c7jh/

If the model becomes larger, solutions like this (i.e. validation rules directly on the UI) do not scale well. For this I like model validations and to that end I created and I am using in my work [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron), a JS validation framework that [binds](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron/tree/master/src/examples/angular) well with Angular (as well as with [others](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron/blob/master/src/examples/react/README.md)).

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
</span>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit"
ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
</p>

</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'John Doe';
    $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide [your source](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_validate) when you use a code you do not write.